# How to take Transpose of a Dataset in scala?

Tags: scala, csv, rdd

I want to take Transpose of a Dataset in scala?

My csv file is,

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
m,n,o,p
```

I need the result as,

```
a,e,i,m
b,f,j,n
c,g,k,o
d,h,l,p
```

Comment: Each of your elements in a is going to be the size of the RDD (which I assume is large). Are you sure you want a List of Lists, or a list of RDDs?)

Comment: We do need to know what you want as output. The "obvious" solutions give `RDD[List[Char]]` but that List is going to be large - one entry for every row of your RDD.  So I suspect you don't want to use  `transpose`, or you want a `List[RDD[Char]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One liner that I think works in Spark.

```
val a = List(
  List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
  List('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'),
  List('i', 'j', 'k', 'l'),
  List('m', 'n', 'o', 'p')
)
val b = sc.parallize(a,1)

 b.flatMap(_.zipWithIndex)
  .groupBy(_._2)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._1))
  .collectAsMap()
  .toList
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .map(_._2)
//> List[Iterable[Char]] = List(
// List(a, e, i, m), List(b, f, j, n), List(c, g, k, o), List(d, h, l, p))
```

Zip each element of each list with its index, then group by that index. So we have maps `0 -> <list of (elements, index) at that index>`. Convert the values to just the list of values. Then convert the result to a list (via a map with `collectAsMap`, as `RDD` doesn't have `.toList`), so we can sort it by index. Then sort it by index and  extract (with another map) just the element values.

Answer (score 1):

Use `transpose` method for it:

```
val a = List(
  List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
  List('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'),
  List('i', 'j', 'k', 'l'),
  List('m', 'n', 'o', 'p')
)

a.transpose

//List(
//  List(a, e, i, m), 
//  List(b, f, j, n), 
//  List(c, g, k, o), 
//  List(d, h, l, p))
```

Comment: My Input is not List[], It is RDD[]